# crux-delete-file-and-buffer (Please commit or undo your changes before deleting)

Tags: git

I try to run crux-delete-file-and-buffer, but it gives me:

```
vc-delete-file: Please commit or undo your changes before deleting
```

Why can't it just delete it?;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the stupid crux* thing and use this;)

```
;; based on http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/03/delete-file-and-buffer/
(defun delete-file-and-buffer ()
  "Kill the current buffer and deletes the file it is visiting."
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (buffer-file-name)))
    (if filename
        (if (y-or-n-p (concat "Do you really want to delete file " filename " ?"))
            (progn
              (delete-file filename)
              (message "Deleted file %s." filename)
              (kill-buffer)))
      (message "Not a file visiting buffer!"))))
```

Found here:
[Github](https://gist.github.com/hyOzd/23b87e96d43bca0f0b52)